# Force Django template to render curly brace values?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this data that comes from a field in the database:

```
item_list = Links.objects.filter(visible=True)
```

In an iteration of item_list there is item.name and item.link. In item.link there could potentially be a string value of

```
'/app/user/{{user.id}}/'.
```

When rendering this particular item.link in a Django template, it comes out literally in html output as:

/app/user/{{user.id}}/

when literally I am hoping for it to render as:

/app/user/1/

Is there any way to force the template to recognize this as a compiled value for output?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render(context, tpl_string):
    t = template.Template(tpl_string)
    return t.render(context)
```

And the in your template:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% render item.link %}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the Template: TemplateSyntaxError at /unitas/
'template_renderer' is not a valid tag library: Template library template_renderer not found. My custom template tag is in this folder: apps/web/templatetags/ called template_renderer.py with __init__.py there as well. In my template, I do {% load template_renderer %} but I still get this error. Any ideas why?

Comment: You should reload the devserver after the creation of template tags library.  Also the `apps.web` should be valid django app added to the `INSTALLED_APS` setting.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Invalid block tag: 'render', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. So you know, this tag is in the midst of a {% for ... %} loop. I tried doing {{ item.link|render }} also.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't do the load in the immediate template. Now it seems to work. Thanks very much for your help, catavaran!